# How much juice is in a lemon?

Tags: measurements, lemon, lemon-juice

A lot of recipes call for the "juice of a lemon". I keep a bottle of lemon juice in the fridge as this is easier, cheaper and more convenient than buying lemons all the time but my problem is I never know how much juice should come out of a lemon. Surely it depends how thoroughly you squeeze it?

Does anyone know approximately what volume of liquid is meant when a recipe says "juice of a lemon"?

Comment: I had the same problem from the opposite end when I lived in California: the tree out back produced *humongous* lemons. The juice of one of those monsters was equivalent to two or three supermarket lemons. Whenever I met a recipe that gave its units in "lemons", I'd sit there wondering, "*Whose* lemons?"

Comment: @Marti I have a grafted lemon tree that gives us  fruit all year around, but winter and summer lemons are VERY different. In summer small and juicy, in winter big and dry.

Comment: As FoodTasted says below, 3 tablespoons will get you in the ballpark; start a little south of there and then let your own taste be the guide. Also, if it isn't too much of a cost or convenience issue, sometime you should do a side-by-side comparison of your refrigerated juice vs.fresh. To me, the refrigerated juice is one-note, lacking all of the brightness of fresh lemons.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It can range on the size of the lemon and the time of year.  A medium lemon will give 2-3 Tablespoons of juice, where a larger lemon can give 1/4 cup (4 Tablespoons).   Just have to decide on much lemon flavor you want in your recipe as to which number you pick.

Comment: The temperature of the lemon will also effect the amount of juice it produces. Microwaving one for 10-20 seconds before squeezing can produce ~1 1/2 times the juice and save your hands some effort.

Answer (score 24):

After searching different places, I could not find a clear answer. I therefor decided to measure it myselfe. I bought a bunch of normal sized lemons, and squeezed them.

On average, the lemons I bought yelded 55ml, thats 3,67 tablespoons of juice per lemon.

Answer (score 3):

I live in Vermont and bought a lemon to squeeze for a recipe and got 5 plus tablespoons so I guess it can range from 3 to 4 to even more!

Answer (score 1):

My lemons make about a quarter cup. They are medium sized, and I live in the northeast.

Comment: The northeast of what?

Comment: @DavidWallace: It must be north of the Middle East, I suppose :)

Answer (score -1):

I think anywhere from 2-6 tablespoons depending on how much lemon flavoring you want.

Comment: Are you trying to say that if you squeeze more it affects the amount of flavor per tablespoon, not just the quantity of juice?

Answer (score -3):

Start with 3 TBL then adjust to YOUR taste!!

Comment: While the amount of juice in a lemon may vary based on the size and composition of the particular lemon, I don't think it is a matter of taste in any way.

Comment: It seems you are answering how to add the 'taste' of the juice of a lemon. While it's not really on topic, that kind of information would be better as a comment.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Since the question does mentions recipes, I don't think it's wrong to say that it _is_ a matter of taste (which is always the case when it comes to cooking).